# ReactJS rendering issue

Tags: reactjs

just began to learn React and here are my very simple JSX and HTML files. I don't see any error in Console (Chrome) when I run it from my http-server. However the button Im expecting to see won't show in the browser. I'm not sure why it does not and what is missing.

Can anyone please help? Also why should we specify type=text/babel" in the  tag? If I don't do this, I get an error (unexpected syntax <) in console.

Thanks!
Prem

**HTML Code:**

```
<html>
<head>  
<title>
    !My first React JS Component!
</title>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="react.js"></script>
    <script src="script.jsx" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**my JSX File:**

```
 var Button = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
              <button> Go! </button>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Button />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: How do you transpile this? Could you share your webpack.config? (If that's what you're using)

Comment: @NicklasWinger sorry to be dumb here. I don't even know what a webpack.config is. I will read through the links you have given below and see if I could fix it. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: Take a look at the links in my answer. Official doc should be easy to understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just include the jsx in your site like that - it won't work :)

You need to transpile your jsx via a tool like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).
The official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html) really is excellent and easy to understand, and it should explain how you setup a basic environment.

Also, there are dozens of tutorials on this, but here's a free one that I found helpful and easy to understand on youtube:

[React + Redux + Webpack](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQDnxXqV213JJFtDaG0aE9vqvp6Wm7nBg) (Feel free to skip the redux part for a starter - really just a popular addon to React for managing state, which you can expand upon later)

For good measure, something like this should work:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>

  <script type="text/babel" src="app.jsx"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

App.jsx:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello React!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```